# How to avoid the instruction "return" inside a function in Symfony2?

Tags: function, symfony, null, return

I would like to know how to avoid the instruction "return" inside a function in Symfony2. In other words how can I make a void function which doesn't return anything. In fact I have tried that for a long time but every time I run the code I did I see this error message: "The controller must return a response" ... By the way, this is the code that I have:

```
public function AddeventsgroupeAction(Request $request) {
    $eventg = new eventsgroupe();
    $form = $this->createForm(new eventsgroupeType(), $eventg);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
    $token = $securityContext->getToken();
    $user = $token->getUser();
    $id = $user->getId();

    $groupe=$this->getRequest('groupe'); 
    $idg = intval($groupe->attributes->get('id'));

   $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
         $qb->select('l')
            ->from('IkprojGroupeBundle:Groupe', 'l')
            ->from('IkprojGroupeBundle:eventsgroupe', 'e')
            ->where(' l.id = :g and e.idGroupe = l.idAdmin and l.id = e.idEventGroupe');

         $qb->setParameter("g", $idg);
         $query = $qb->getQuery();
         $res = $query->getResult();

          $rows = array();
    foreach ($res as $obj) {
        $rows[] = array(

          'id' => $obj->getId());

    }


    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $eventg-> setIdGroupe($id);
            $eventg-> setIdEventGroupe($idg);
            $em->persist($eventg);


            $em->flush();


            return $moslem="yes";
        }
    } else {

        return $this->render('IkprojGroupeBundle:GroupeEvents:Addeventgroupe.html.twig', array(
                    'groupe' => $rows,
                    'event' => $eventg,
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

}
```

How can I replace the instruction : `return $moslem="yes";` in order to not return anything??...Is that possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your basic question, a simple return will return a void from your function.

The "controller must return a response" message actually comes from the request handler.  You need to tell the request handler what you want it to do.  There is no default page so a void return will trigger the error.

In most cases, after successfully processing a posted form you will want to return a redirect response.

Something like:

```
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        ...
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
```

I should point out that your form code seems to be from S2.1 or older.  It's unnecessarily complicated.  You should be using at least 2.3.  Make sure you are looking at the correct version of the documentation.  Hint:  the isValid() takes care of the POST check.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

It's also worth while to understand the request/response workflow.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html

Digging into the code can also help in understanding where the error message is coming from:

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel#handleRaw($request)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, delete the `else` statement and if `$request->isMethod('POST')` or `$form->isValid()` returns false the code inside will not be executed then the script return the default view.

**EDIT**: you can also make a redirect with a flash message where needed like this:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'your success message');
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('your_route'));
```

Remember to add support for flash message in your view looking at the [Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages)

Comment: well, concerning the instructions: else , if $request->isMethod('POST') , $form->isValid() I can't delete them for some reasons. By the way, how can I make a redirect with a flash message?..can you give me an example?

Comment: I edited my answer but always look at the docs before ask here (specially the cookbook), where you'll find all the basic use cases (and not only...)